# Разные обработчики click для классов в Ext.XTemplate

Tags: extjs

Есть обработчик клика для всего блока:

```
listeners: {
   click: {
      element: 'el',
      deligate: '.results-row',
      preventDefault: true,
      fn: this.resultsClickHandler,
      scope: this
   }
}
```

Нужно сделать для .result-row td:nth-child(2), .result-row td:nth-child(3) и .result-row td:nth-child(7) Разные обработчики клика.